# How to avoid hdinsight on demand in azure data factory from creating a new container everytime

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight, azure-data-factory

When using hdinsight on demand in azure data factory, it creates a new blob container every time it runs. I'd like to point it to an existing blob storage or at least prevent it from creating a new blob storage every time it runs. Can I do that?

Comment: are you using manage.windowsazure.com or portal.azure.com

Comment: I'm using portal.azure.com

Answer (score 0):

Azure Data Factory (ADF) specifies **name of data factory**-**name of the linked service**-**date time stamp** as the name of the container each time it creates an on-demand HDI cluster. It truncates if the name is too long.

By default, when the cluster is deleted, the underlying storage container associated with the cluster is not removed. This is the behavior of HDInsight, not ADF.

As mentioned above, ADF does not use the same container; it is by design at this time. I have passed on your feedback about being able to mention a specific container as part of the JSON to the product team.

Comment: so I have a pipeline in which the first activity is an HDInsight activity and generates a file and the second activity is a copy activity and wants to copy the file to documentdb. however as the container for the hdinsight cluster is different everytime, the second activity fails. I used the same dataset for the output of the first activity and input of the second one, and user keyword 'container' as the container name, but it just doesn't work. Any solution?

Comment: Looks like it's still same in 2017, HDInsight on demand creates new container every time it runs.

Answer (score 0):

Sreedhar - This is a big issue for the HDInsight On Demand functionality in ADF.  I am attempting to run HDInsightOnDemand on a 1 hour interval and it is creating a lot of containers.