# Get HD Insight Cluster on demand cluster name

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I've created a cluster On Demand in HD-Insight (Using Azure Data Factory). Therefore the name of the cluster is: prefix + timestamp. According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33795090/how-to-avoid-hdinsight-on-demand-in-azure-data-factory-from-creating-a-new-conta) there is no new functionality to fix the cluster name.

I want to submit a Livy job in a power shell as script in Azure Data Factory. But in order to do that i need to provide the cluster name. Exist any possibility to get the current name of the cluster in order to use to submit a job with Livy.

Answer (score 0):

I think the ask is to get the on demand cluster name , so that the cluster name can be passed on to other activities . I did reached out to some internals teams and as per them it does not look to be possible at this time .

Comment: @jqc Did you check the HDinsight Linked service

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you already got your solution and this is for reference for others.
There is no need to get the cluster name, you can create a pipeline in ADF(with on-demand HDI linked service) and then store your jar/script in Azure storage

[image]

[image]

You can also trigger the pipeline using rest-api

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{{sub_id}}/resourceGroups/{{resource_group_name}}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{{factory_name}}/pipelines/{{pipeline_name}}/createRun?api-version=2018-06-01
```

Or if you still need the Cluster name,

Then you can write a custom Powershell(using `Get-AzHDInsightCluster` along with String operations or if-else) to print the exact cluster name(you can add a prefix to the cluster so that it will be easy to use with String operations).You can automate it using Custom activity in ADF
[image]

Sample Powershell command

```
(Get-AzHDInsightCluster|out-string) -split "`n" | select-string <Cluster Name Prefix>
```

**Or**,

```
 (Get-AzHDInsightCluster|out-string) -split "`n" | select-string -pattern "Name                       :" -caseSensitive
```

Comment: Yeah! But the cluster name would still have the timestamp in its name. What do I want to avoid

Comment: You need not avoid anything. You can customize(use wild character) the PowerShell command above to get all the deployed cluster names from the current subscription. I have added another command as per your need

Comment: If this answers your query, please mark it as a solution so that it will be helpful to others

Comment: Hello! Nop This answer not solve my doubt. Thanks!

Comment: What you are trying to achieve @jqc?